# Do two TensorFlow models on different python files conflict?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, tensorflow

I have a TensorFlow model that in each training episode I need to run a function on the data in that episode. This function is also a TensorFlow model in another python file that I import to the main file. This function trains the classifier on the data and returns the result to the main function.

Does the training process of the model in the function (which is the other python file) mess up with the training of the model in the main file? doesn't the update of the weights in two models get overwritten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weights are saved into .data files and your graph and metadata are saved into the .meta file.

Also, the actual real weights only exists within a Session. It means that the “restore” action must have access to a session to restore weights inside a Graph.

Particular to your question, you are right, if you overwrite .data files from a different python script the weight values would be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks, I don't save any of two models, even if they are running at the same time the weights are written in the same .data and .meta files?

Comment: What is the solution? how can I train and test a separate classifier on the data in each eposide of the training of another model without any interference among their parameters?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question well. If you are not saving and reading from the same files, there is no issue at all and both models using the same function will be trained separately .